# Textfield text alignment is not aligned vertically

Tags: flutter, textfield, vertical-alignment

I am trying to build a form with custom textfield height, i would like to make the textfield text and hit text to be center vertically. Here is my code

```
      SizedBox(
             height: 40,
              child:
              TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
                textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                maxLines: 1,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Color(0xff5a9fd6).withOpacity(0.15),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Color(0xff5a9fd6).withOpacity(1.0),
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1.0),
                    )
                ),
              )
          ),
```

When i decrease the font size then the text is aligned vertically but i would like to use the font size as 14 and above.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can to adjust `contentPadding` to center your text vertically, for example:

```dart
TextField(
decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(<your value>),
)
```

Comment: but it is not working if i change the height of the Sizedbox. i want to have a text field in 60x60 size, the text should be in center of this box .

Answer (score 2):

Do not wrap the TextField from SizeBox to manage the height of the TextField. You can do this by using vertical contentPadding as follows. It keeps your text in the center.

```
TextField(
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14,
    ),
    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    maxLines: 1,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
         contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50, horizontal: 20),
         filled: true,
         fillColor: Color(0xff5a9fd6).withOpacity(0.15),
         focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Color(0xff5a9fd6).withOpacity(1.0),
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1.0),
          )
     ),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `contentPadding` of the `TextField` as 0 or according to your requirement.

```
SizedBox(
             height: 40,
              child:
              TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),

                textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                maxLines: 1,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Color(0xff5a9fd6).withOpacity(0.15),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Color(0xff5a9fd6).withOpacity(1.0),
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1.0),
                    )
                ),
              )
          ),
```

Comment: if i change the height of sizedbox to 80 then the textfield is size is not increasing to occupy entire height, also the cursor is not in the center of the textfield.